# PHP integral arguments such as in curl_setopt and filter_var

Tags: php

I've been browsing the documentation relentlessly, but I just can't seem to figure out what it's called when a function uses an argument which has an int datatype. For example, in filter_var:

```
filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

... or in curl

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com');
```

What is FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL and CURLOPT_URL called?

Comment: They're [constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). Named identifiers are easier to remember and read than magic/enumerated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called [Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

It just a variable, but because it is constant it should be written as Capital letters just to distinguish from other types of variables.That's the naming convention.

```
define('YOUR_CONSTANT', '894616466');
echo YOUR_CONSTANT;//894616466
```

Answer (score 0):

These are called "Predefined Constants". They're published by category i.e.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.constants.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php